# Run html file that has associated php file on mac

Tags: php, html, server

I am making a contact us page for a website. I have the html page defining all the input criteria such as name, email and message. This html file links to a php file to send the information that the user types into the message box.

my problem is that I cannot test if sending the message will work as I think the php file needs to to be run through a server. How can i test if the file works on my mac?

Comment: Indeed the usual approach is to use some http server with php as a module inside. So the answer here is: you have to install and setup a http server. Which usually is only a few clicks ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your .php file in the htdocs folder of MAMP or XAMP. After that you must copy your file path in your browser. Replace everything up to and including htdocs with your localhost. For example: If my file is in Users/Documents/MAMP/htdocs/index.php it should be like localhost:8888/index.php

Comment: this is the answer. think you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can download mamp or xamp and install server on your mac. Then you can test your all php files.

Comment: Thanks that spot on. I downloaded MAMP but when I ran the php via my html the php file opens in the browser but it appears as text. any ideas?

Comment: save your file as .php not html